# $P(U_2S_2<U_1S_1)$

Tags: probability

Let $U_1$ and $U_2$ are iid continuous random variable over $(0,1)$ and $S_1$ and $S_2$ are iid continuous random variable over $(-\infty,+\infty)$. Then what is $$P(U_2S_2<U_1S_1)?$$

I think it is $1/2$, because  $U_1S_1$ and $U_2S_2$ are identically distributed. My main confusion is: am I right in assuming $U_1S_1$ and $U_2S_2$ are identically distributed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $f_U(u)$ is the pdf of both $U_1, U_2$, and $f_S(s)$ is the pdf of both $S_1, S_2$, then $f_{US}(z)=\int_0^1 \frac{1}{u} f_U(u)f_S(z/u)\operatorname d u$ is the pdf for the product distribution of both $U_1S_1,U_2S_2$.

So, yes, $U_1S_1$ and $U_2S_2$ will be identically distributed.

However, we can only assert that $U_1S_1$ and $U_2S_2$ will independent if we *also* know that $U_1$ and $S_2$ are independent and that $U_2$ and $S_1$ are too.

Answer (score 1):

Yes! To dispelled your confusion, just consider $U$ and $S$. Their product $US$ follows some distribution, call it $F$. But it could have been $X$ and $Y$, as long as $X\overset{d}{=} U$ and $Y \overset{d}{=} S$. Then $XY\sim F$. Similar for $U_1,U_2,S_1,S_2$, you are just playing with the names.